# Xpra proxy: How Can I forwading a server which inside work and without xpra to html5 client?

Tags: x11, java, xpra

I'm trying to forwarding a X application ,but the server having this X application can't install xpra.

```
xpra start  --bind-tcp=0.0.0.0:12345  --html=on --start=xlogo
```

it works,and i can visit web page successful.

this command forwarding application to html5 client  but

```
xpra start ssh://SERVERHOSTNAME@SERVERHOST/  --bind-tcp=0.0.0.0:12345  --html=on --start=xlogo
```

Can't make my needs realistic.

log looks fine，but it didn't work

Comment: Do you get any error messages?  Please [edit] your question, and add that information, and also put  four spaces in front of your command lines to make it easier to see the commands used.  Thanks.

Comment: what I want do is openning a remote mechine's application in broswer,and that mechine 
 not need to install xpra

Comment: @MingLouis you can't, realistically. Xpra needs to be installed on the host where your application is going to run. Theoretically, you could export a remote display and run xpra that way, but that's crazy inefficient and brittle.